# How to convert Phaser keyboard event into touch event

Tags: javascript, touch, phaser-framework

I am following a Fruit Ninja tutorial using Phaser. For the main menu, the author has used

```
if (this.game_state.game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR)) {
    this.menu_items[this.current_item_index].select();
```

How would I implement that same logic using touch events so I can use it on my tablet/phone? The rest of the swipe logic is using touch, except for the menu. I was wondering how I could change that.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me to be more than a just simple "change this to that". The code snippet you've posted makes it look to me that the menu keeps some kind of a current index of which menu item is highlighted (maybe using the arrow keys?).

If your menu is composed of sprites for example, you can attach a touch event to each sprite. Say you have a sprite called `exitGameMenuItem` in the menu. You need to enable its input and attach an `onInputDown` event callback to it (and it will work with both mouse and touch).

```
exitGameMenuItem.inputEnabled = true;
exitGameMenuItem.events.onInputDown.add(function() {
    // call the exit game function here
}, this);
```

Alternatively you can add the callback directly (without wrapping it in a function) like this:

```
exitGameMenuItem.events.onInputDown.add(this.exitGame, this);
```

(This assumes that you have an `exitGame()` function in the same state).

Comment: Yes, the code is using an index to switch between main menu items. They are changed by arrow keys and upon hitting the space bar it selects the currently selected menu item. Is there a way to select the menu item using a touch event instead of the spacebar?

Comment: Yes, I explained just that.

Comment: How do I get this to work using the Phaser framework?

Comment: I gave you an example. Without seeing more of your code, I can't help you more I'm afraid.

Comment: Here is the menu function: if (this.cursor_keys.up.isDown && this.current_item_index > 0) {
        // navigate to previous item
        this.menu_items[this.current_item_index].selection_out();
        this.current_item_index -= 1;
        this.menu_items[this.current_item_index].selection_over();

Comment: What sprites are displayed in the menu state?